# Asynchronously loop through array with key

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I have an array of customers and I want to loop through them and assign each one a property. The customer object with the added property is returned via the details function

```
for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++)
{
    customers[i] = await details(customers[i]);
}
```

This is how im doing it at the moment but its synchronous. I want all objects in the list to be done at once asyncronously. I am trying with the async library but it only gives me the customer object thats available inside of the loop, so the customers array will never change.

```
async.forEachOf(customers, (customer, finished) async =>
{
    customer = await details(customer);
    finished();
});
```

How else would I do this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what you're asking for. The first code example is the sort of thing I think you want to do, it's not really clear with your descriptions why it's wrong.

Comment: If you take the first example, and change it to `customers[i].details = await details(customers[i]);`, is that closer to what you want?

Comment: yes its doing exactly what I need but its synchronous. Lets say there is 10 customers, I want all 10 to be done at the same time. The details function returns the customer with the added properties so I want to update that customer by using customers[i] whereas in the 2nd example, customer is defined within the function, so after I cannot return the list of customers with their added functions

Comment: `s/synchronous/sequential`. You're using "synchronous" wrong.

Comment: OH, you want them to be done at the same time. That's easy, I'll make a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a third-party library to accomplish this. Just use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const customerDetails = await Promise.all(
  customers.map(customer => details(customer))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [library is not required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhBSDGB7AdgNwKYoJZYRyAMwFcUEAXbVIpAJ0VowENKUBzSJyAUQGUAmAAwBGAKyQA4lgy0WdSOSSRs5GSwJJMtKDBUYAtgGdlKTqaa1ZATwB0OnZAACGAB4AHOuQePV%20twBt1SAAVbzcLJn1IAG9ggG0AXQBfSDQmf2IMHWBwEjJKVBhFAElVWUVaAB5ggD4ACjSMjAAuEMSAShioRFRDckg2aXL5AF5U9My43it9ACMkfxs9YdoEuvaAbm7CeTr-DH7BlDVVABNIJEIBoblaTujuyEgrXH9zo5OMU62npPA-8CgCDQSAABVommwpwwxnIAAsCExZth-CorAolG4IfhDMYmKZlrcAOTGRqZPGGKxkOEQlBIYiGfxWBwAdxUcM4kCxX2wCHUABpIAADOH46G0IV2aDeVweWheEE%20AwBIKhRW%20FWqEIAJQOxFoKG8GsCWuCADlXAqYI5wrIotEpMcVtVBcFdeR9ShXRaXOQaikPiswhF7XULGxWsFOiMamCIfpsIYMNV3Z7-ZBRShTvttIrGB6DYZsuAmJSyERSBQqASyupYGWEDTUPTGVYXTq9QbvZb6t1A7dWo6TnR227O16Qj6-fzupnszJWmHaBGQtHY%20CkAmkynxzVwPdusgUH1lLXVIu13HN4nk2OCyhY2NS1SEJB1pAY10nk8jyf%202cP2uJ1bhsY5fXWH5v2wK46n-L4bFOVAMAPb9v3zT0gM%20U4bDJDBIN%20R5IHQg0MzFHNYJuM4cImZCbHhLA6kJVRNm6JJIOImtPgg-5wHAX9%20gsegxjiYRBX4QUAGZBQAFgSLZwCYjB6xfJs6QZJk6hKM86CXO5BQadJL2OFkry3DA6iE2MHlQpNyGCbB9AwelyAssTBHcljUN-BYMBsfwkDYOoiQ3HFDGwdgiUFRoWKSdpNiAA) to iterate over an array of items asynchronously.

For example, to process this array asynchronously:

`const arr = [1, 2, 3];`

First, create a generator from an array so that can you yield execution for each item in the array:

```
/**
 * A convenience function for creating a ES2015 Generator to iterate over
 * items in an array.
 *
 * @template T
 * @param {T[]} value
 */
function* toIterator<T>(value: T[]) {
  const generator = value[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (let generated of generator) {
    yield generated;
  }
}
```

Then, the key to iterating over the array asynchronously is to have a function call itself on the `resolve` of the provided `handler`.

```
/**
 * Provides the ability to process an iterator's values asynchronously
 * with a predicate, `hander`.
 *
 * @template T
 * @template TReturn
 * @template TNext
 * @param {Generator<T, TReturn, TNext>} generator
 * @param {(arg: T) => Promise<TReturn>} handler
 * @returns
 */
async function iterateAsynchronously<T, TReturn, TNext>(
  generator: Generator<T, TReturn, TNext>,
  handler: (arg: T) => Promise<TReturn>
) {
  const iterate: () => Promise<TReturn> = async () => {
    const generated = generator.next();
    if (generated.done) {
      return generated.value;
    }
    return handler(generated.value).then(iterate);
  };
  return iterate();
}
```

If you prefer, you can extend the global Array with one or both of these methods. [Another example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcoF4oB4AqAfABRzoDmAXFPgJTaFQAK6A9gLYCWAzhLgILp0cEAUKEA3ACgpAegBU8qVHlR%20UAMasEANwgJO%20jdABmAVwQbgnbVBOtMG9BDjWE5KHCgBRAMoAmAAYARgBWKABxfQxXByhgVihOYBiUqFY9dGVVZIh2biSETyKyYRAAOmzsqAABCAAPMAdgapqU9jAUV2h8VrAyOHYoAG98AG0AXQBfKB04FDMIbNkpc0trbVUEgEkU4QT0MWI5hYhqcYn6YeVNbW5gKHJo-bicE8Wx3xB2ACNWFHKuRe6AmxFo0igdjixDQDyeCFSECQ6RMj2esXQVxukJAhhQyPhiKQEKgUykZKknAQexMcGMaiEIjEIxuCiUkJUzDYOk4SAgBWAAAtoHAfpwUMkQPFEmA2MZuAVEEk9hiAOQFd78zzcECWQVsBCsMzcFAgbGqADuyUFnigsqRnA03QANFAAAaCxB89Buyoc9mQ1R1RrNc21dqdbo0MNtPKRtL4ABKEGAZnQCBjEa6CYAcg0Wv7av1hENhlEEcCCK6kym0whq3n6sBCDNCcCY8XBiN4Mg0OgZp7exgY85U%20nuOaVpCgd1%20Dq9QajSaQMQnSgUD86QBrEwIaikCjnehYRgsDg8PiCMpiQi0ahnri8ASM0RESTkmRXkTlWWsBKgSBARVFI511DR9W0JdTWwOwLCsGwiiONcN23XdqB7VAMCxSEtAQe40QrDEYJ2YCHGfa832IIUeHBG5cPwmcUn3Y9TzYR9LxfG8YLgecNCgMEGBZDlbjwuF0RSZEcDbDFygRJswRJadUWIaSJPKJBtAgbDhKgUc63iQUeEU0lsV02t000eYUI0HcEBU8SkXKTVaHKIV9GIRitJJKYST0izPIU8lpCkeiHnQCxuN4-iWKEkT8NKGCxmCV1-FdABmV0ABYJhJej-ggcoUFYchiFIC04GSTwhCAxFQIXSDjVNUqThihELS5c9eGITAT1iyFeGAfBOHYCAjWAbqUsCKbaOEvK0EK4riFVM95W4KlyFVV0Wu82hdvKZxMi63bpDJcK7PBIA)

This would allow you to chain more array methods together after processing the items asynchronously:

```
const run = async () => {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  console.log((await arr.iterateAsynchronously((val) => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, 2000);
    console.log('Processing', val);
  }))).reverse());
}
run();
```

In this case, since the array prototype is modified with the function extension that returns the array itself, you can chain array methods together like you are used to.

Answer (score -1):

This code will run `details()` for each customer one after the other without waiting for the previous one. You create an array of promises and await them all at the end

```
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    let p = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      customers[i] = await details(customers[i]);
      resolve();
    });
    promises.push(p);
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: It's still wrong. This is why promise construction is an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You haven't properly handled errors. It would be correct if you just `let p = details(customers[i])`, albeit still much more verbose than necessary.